# How Setup PHP development environment to use Eclipse IDE, IIS,Team Foundation Server(TFS)

Tags: php, eclipse, iis-7

I am new to PHP scripting language. Basically I am a .Net guy, worked on various web applications using MVC, Razor, ASP.NET, C#...etc. I thought this the best time to practice on PHP and planning to start work on projects using PHP.

I am trying to setup PHP development environment in my local machine.

Please guide me in the following questions.

1. What are the available software’s I need to install in my machine to start PHP development (SQL, IIS, PHP scrip, TFS)?
2. In order to create team project I want to use Team Foundation Server (TFS) within the eclipse IDE. Pease tell me someone, how to connect TFS from eclipse IDE (or) any alternate ways?
3. How to configure IIS to server PHP web pages? Do I need to install additional software other than eclipse?

I have done the following steps,

1. I downloaded Java from [java.com](http://java.com/en/).
2. I downloaded eclipse from [eclipse.org](http://eclipse.org/downloads/) then installed to my machine and pointed to default workspace(C:/users/xxxx/workspace).
3. Installed add-on phpeclipse to eclipse IDE. This add-on downloaded from [phpeclipse.com](http://phpeclipse.sourceforge.net/update/stable/1.2.x/)
   Open Eclipse IDE=> help=> Install New Software=> Add.

Name: [PHPEclipse]

Location: [http://phpeclipse.sourceforge.net/update/stable/1.2.x/]

Ok=> followed instruction to complete installation.

### After completing the above steps, I just created a new PHP project then wrote echo statement in .php page but it prompting me below error when I run my test project

[image]